# How to insert hexBinary data to subjectAltName in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

I need my X.509 version 3 certificate's subjectAltName to have hexBinary data (binary contents coded in hexadecimal).

Example (UUID?): 25289a27a9ad4510ab20135a96050d09.

When using

```
subjectAltName = otherName:2.25;FORMAT:HEX,OCTETSTRING:25289a27a9ad4510ab20135a96050d09
```

For some reason, OpenSSL shows CSR's or certificate's X509V3 Subject Alternative Name to have othername: < unsupported>

hxtools shows that it is unknown:

```
subjectAltName otherName 2.25 unknown
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

That is probably pretty much as you should expect. Try outputting it through ans1parse and then rerun the command with a -strparse  to the point of your SubjectAlternative name. You should see the octed string then if all is well.