# SubjectAltName otherName with binary value

Tags: openssl, certificate

I am trying to embed binary data to otherName field using the `X509V3_EXT_conf_nid` function. I am having problems with specifying the proper ASN1 type.

When giving `otherName:0.4.0.127.0.7;OCT:AABB` the result is `41 41 42 42`, which is I guess the default ASCII formatting mentioned [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ASN1_generate_nconf.html#SUPPORTED_TYPES). If I want OpenSSL to interpret the `AABB` as binary value, I should use the HEX option. But no matter what I do, nothing works.

Using the [all present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626812/how-to-insert-hexbinary-data-to-subjectaltname-in-openssl) `FORMAT:HEX,OCT:AABB` gives me error:220A4093:X509 V3 routines: a2i_GENERAL_NAME: othername error.

Using trial and error and using something like `HEX,OCT:AABB` or `OCT,HEX:AABB` gets me nowhere with "unknown tag" and "unsupported option" errors.

So what should I do to convince OpenSSL to accept the suplied data?

Maybe it is worth mentioning that I am calling the OpenSSL functions through the ManagedOpenSSL wrapper.

Comment: I don't think its possible. The names are usually UTF-8 or Printable String. I don't think I've come across binary data. Do you know of a spec that allows it?

Comment: The specification I am following is not accessible to the public, but is part of the [MS2020](http://www.vde.com/en/fnn/pages/ms2020.aspx) project. The gist of it is this. Some Id is in binary. That id must be in extension of a certificate. The specification does not specify the exact form of that extension so I am assuming that they mean that the extension data must also be binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after getting a tumbleweed achievement, putting this thing on hold for a month and then returning back to it, I think I cracked it.

I used the [arbitrary extension](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html#ARBITRARY_EXTENSIONS). Sure, I have to know how to construct the DER format for the appropriate ASN1 structure, but that is not so hard.

If anyone can see some flaw with this approach, please let me know.

Comment: The URL is not valid anymore. Since I cannot edit the post, I add a fresh one here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/x509v3_config.html#ARBITRARY-EXTENSIONS